# Airflow - Failed to fetch log file from worker. 404 Client Error: NOT FOUND for url

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am running Airflowv1.9 with Celery Executor. I have 5 Airflow workers running in 5 different machines. Airflow scheduler is also running in one of these machines. I have copied the same airflow.cfg file across these 5 machines.
I have daily workflows setup in different queues like DEV, QA etc. (each worker runs with an individual queue name) which are running fine.

While scheduling a DAG in one of the worker (no other DAG have been setup for this worker/machine previously), I am seeing the error in the 1st task and as a result downstream tasks are failing:

```
*** Log file isn't local.
*** Fetching here: http://<worker hostname>:8793/log/PDI_Incr_20190407_v2/checkBCWatermarkDt/2019-04-07T17:00:00/1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. 404 Client Error: NOT FOUND for url: http://<worker hostname>:8793/log/PDI_Incr_20190407_v2/checkBCWatermarkDt/2019-04-07T17:00:00/1.log
```

I have configured MySQL for storing the DAG metadata. When I checked task_instance table, I see proper hostnames are populated against the task.

I also checked the log location and found that the log is getting created.

**airflow.cfg snippet:**

```
base_log_folder = /var/log/airflow
base_url = http://<webserver ip>:8082
worker_log_server_port = 8793
api_client = airflow.api.client.local_client
endpoint_url = http://localhost:8080
```

What am I missing here? What configurations do I need to check additionally for resolving this issue?

Comment: Shouldnt the base url point to webserver ip ?You have mentioned it as scheduler ip address

Comment: Yeah the scheduler and webserver were running in the same node. Will update the airflow.cfg snippet accordingly. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the worker's hostname is not being correctly resolved.
Add a file `hostname_resolver.py`:

```
import os
import socket
import requests
def resolve():
    """
    Resolves Airflow external hostname for accessing logs on a worker
    """
    if 'AWS_REGION' in os.environ:
        # Return EC2 instance hostname:
        return requests.get(
            'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4').text
    # Use DNS request for finding out what's our external IP:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(('1.1.1.1', 53))
    external_ip = s.getsockname()[0]
    s.close()
    return external_ip
```

And export: `AIRFLOW__CORE__HOSTNAME_CALLABLE=airflow.hostname_resolver:resolve`

Comment: Where to add this python file? I'm also facing the same issue and using CeleryExecutor with Mysql database on Airflow 2.0.0

Comment: @Nikita anywhere you want, just make sure you load it with your dockerfile

Comment: I'm not using docker. So can I place this in plugins directory?

Comment: It’s better to create a new folder and not to mix it with the plugins

Comment: I created a config folder and put it there. For 2.1 the syntax was slightly changed to AIRFLOW__CORE__HOSTNAME_CALLABLE=airflow.hostname_resolver.resolve

Comment: I updated the files and exported the value but looks same issue in version 2.02.

Answer (score 0):

The web program of the master needs to go to the worker to fetch the log and display it on the front-end page. This process is to find the host name of the worker. Obviously, the host name cannot be found,Therefore, add the host name to IP mapping on the master's `vim /etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

If this happens as part of a Docker Compose Airflow setup, the hostname resolution needs to be passed to the container hosting the webserver, e.g. through [extra_hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts):

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3.9"

services:
  webserver:
    extra_hosts:
      - "worker_hostname_0:192.168.xxx.yyy"
      - "worker_hostname_1:192.168.xxx.zzz"
    ...
  ...
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74901095/8929855).