# Airflow - Failed to fetch log file

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to create a simple DAG workflow on Apache Airflow where data is updated to my localhost PostgreSQL database.

Can someone please tell me why my DAG fails and I get these errors in the logs ONLY when I use CeleryExecutor? I tried running the same DAG using LocalExecutor and I didn't get any errors and it run smoothly.

This is the log errors:

```
*** Log file isn't local.
*** Fetching here: http://<worker hostname>:8793/log/PDI_Incr_20190407_v2/checkBCWatermarkDt/2019-04-07T17:00:00/1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. 404 Client Error: NOT FOUND for url: http://<worker hostname>:8793/log/PDI_Incr_20190407_v2/checkBCWatermarkDt/2019-04-07T17:00:00/1.log
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best solution**

If you want to see logs on your web, you need to configure the hostname mapping of the /etc/hosts of the worker node, mapping the ip of the worker node to the hostname of the machine:

```
10.xxx.xxx.xxx  hostname
```

And your request after that:

```
http://hostname.pl:8793/log/..
```

**Fast solution**

If you don't want to do that you can see logs in your worker node  airflow/logs/{dagName}/{taskName}/{executionTimestamp}/log.txt

In your case it will be airflow/logs/PDI_Incr_20190407_v2/checkBCWatermarkDt/2019-04-07T17:00:00/1.log

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with a missing hostname resolution. The fix depends on whether the webserver is running in a Docker container.

###### The webserver is *not* running in a Docker container

Modify `etc/hosts` (assuming Linux) by adding the hostname resolution:

```
# etc/hosts

...
192.168.xxx.yyy  airflow-worker0
192.168.xxx.zzz  airflow-worker1
```

###### The webserver *is* running in a Docker container

Assuming a Docker Compose setup, pass the hostname resolution as [extra_hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts) for the webserver service:

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3.9"

services:
  webserver:
    extra_hosts:
      - "airflow-worker0:192.168.xxx.yyy"
      - "airflow-worker1:192.168.xxx.zzz"
    ...
  ...
```